# Is it possible to scroll by page in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a UIScroll View that scrolls vertically, each cell contains a UIScrollView that scrolls horizontally. I created it using information in this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2) I want the Horizontal table to scroll page by page (the same way your home screen would scroll if you have multiple pages of apps. Is this possible in a UITableView?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you checked out UIPageView ?

Comment: Yeah- I took a look at it, I dont think you can have a table of pages so that it can scroll vertically and horizontally with a UIPageView. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a UITableView with multiple cells and those are holding UIScrollViews that scroll horizontally, right?

You can set pagingEnabled for a UIScrollView like this:

```
[_scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

Just make sure the contentSize of the UIScrollView is at least 2x bigger then it's frame width, so that you can actually 'page' your way around :)